# Continuity equation, why doesn't it apply here?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

[image]

In this question above, I am confused with why the continuity theorem do not apply here. Since I think this is still a laminar flow of incompressible fluid. What do I not understand about the applicability of the continuity theorem?

What should I use instead to solve this problem? I'm assuming Bernoulli's theorem? Why should I instead assume the velocity of flow at the top of tube is 0? How do I deduce that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to solve the problem is to use Bernoulli's principle along with the following constraint: for the siphon to work, the pressure must be positive throughout the system. Using Bernoulli's principle (with the idealization that the velocity is zero at the surface of the reservoir), we get

$$ \frac{p_{\textrm{atm}}}{\rho} = \frac{p_{\textrm{peak}}}{\rho} + \frac{v^2}{2} + gH $$

where $ v $ is the flow velocity inside the tube. $ H $ will be maximized in this equation if $ p_{\textrm{peak}} = 0 $ and $ v = 0 $, so the maximum possible $ H $ is

$$ H_{\textrm{max}} = \frac{p_{\textrm{atm}}}{\rho g} $$

As for your question about the continuity equation, it does apply here: the flow velocity $ v $ is constant throughout the entire tube. However, in this application of Bernoulli's principle we are comparing the velocity *at the surface of the reservoir* with the velocity *inside the tube*, which aren't equal and aren't required to be by the continuity equation.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I still have a confusion: By the continuity equation then, the velocity inside the tube should be equal to the velocity in the end of the tube. Now velocity in the end of the tube at the opening is given as $v = \sqrt{2gh}$ by bernoulli's principle. Why then, does that become $v = 0$ at the top?

Comment: @LHC2012 See the formula for the maximum velocity through a siphon at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphon. The velocity is constant throughout the tube, but if the maximum velocity the siphon can support is less than $ \sqrt{2gh} $, the siphon will simply fail to work. This means you can't increase $ h $ indefinitely to get higher and higher velocities forever.

Comment: So your point is that the siphon will transport fluid with fluid speed of $\sqrt{2gh}$ so long as the height is below the threshold? If not, the fluid will not reach the top of siphon to begin with?

Comment: @LHC2012 No, because the Bernoulli principle argument only works in a "steady state" of flow where you have a flow of fluid throughout the tube. When the fluid is initially entering the tube the Bernoulli principle argument obviously doesn't apply. What would happen in this case is that the flow would start out fine, but once the flow tries to settle into some steady state, you would get bubbles forming in the negative pressure regions of the tube which would impede the steady state flow.